# Why does extracting a value to a 'var' variable change behaviour?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am using EasyMoq (http://wp7fx.codeplex.com/) as a mocking framework in a Windows Store application. In the setup code for a test case, I have code that looks like this:

```
var mock = Easy.Moq.Mock<SomeClass>();
mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod("an arg", Allow.Any<AnotherClass>())).Returns("a value");
```

**This code works properly.** For those of you not familiar with EasyMoq, `Easy.Moq.Mock<...>()` instantiates a mock and `mock.Setup(m => m.XYZ()).Returns(...)` configures the mock to return a value when it receives a call to the mock's `XYZ()` method. The `Allow.Any<T>()` expression indicates that it should match on any value. By looking at its source code, apparently it simply returns `default(T)`. The details are not that important.

Because that was a very long statement, I decided to break it up by extracting the `Allow.Any<...>()` expression into an implicitly variable, like so:

```
var mock = Easy.Moq.Mock<SomeClass>();
var arg = Allow.Any<AnotherClass>();
mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod("an arg", arg)).Returns("a value");
```

However, this code fails due to an `System.NullReferenceException` after invoking the method on the mock. It's probably a bug in EasyMoq, but my question is this:

**How could this refactoring alter the behaviour of the code?**

Comment: I can tell you one thing, it has nothing to do with `var`. In C# `var` has no special meaning. It is only allowed if the compiler can infer the type from the RHS expression, otherwise your code won't compile. The use of `var` does not make your type dynamic or anything of the sort. If I do `var name = "evan";` `name` is compiled as a string. If my RHS expression was ambiguous I would just get a compiler error.

Comment: I believe most of the Moq `Setup`/`Return` code takes expressions and looks through them to build actual mock. Likely after your change it no longer able to properly walk through the expression tree to build validator.

Comment: If `Allow.Any()` returns `default(T)`, what's the value/type of `arg` if you step through the code? I'd suspect it would be `null` given your description, but that still wouldn't explain why it works when in-line but not when extracted to a variable.

Comment: Could you take a peek at the generated CIL code of both versions to see what is different there?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: You and David Haney seem to be both correct. I wish I could "accept" a comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be willing to bet that `.Setup` signature involves Expressions... It likely inspects the inputs as expressions and evaluates them... and since your var statement (where the var doesn't matter) EVALUATES the `Allow.Any<T>` call, the expression then parses `default(T)` instead of `Allow.Any<T>`... Can you show us the `.Setup` signature?

Comment: This appears to be correct. Based on the disassembled IL, it is indeed using Expressions to process the `.Setup` statement, so the explanation is plausible that it can't process it if the `Allow.Any<T>` call has already been evaluated and placed in a temporary variable.